# How do I redirect a Django form submit to a new tab after form validation?

Tags: django

1. I have a Django form with two dropdown integer fields and a submit button.
2. A user selects values from these dropdown fields and click on submit button.
3. The Django template performs a form 'post' and sends these two dropdown values to my Django views.
4. Django views performs the form validation by validating these two dropdown fields values.
5. If the form is not valid, it will send the error message to the Django template and I can display the error message on the same form page above the form.
6. If the form is valid, then it will redirect to a new URL.

***Issue***: How do I tell my Django view to redirect the URL to a new tab only after the form is valid?

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you're already familiar with [Djangos Form View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview). Within the `form_valid(self, form)` method of your class based view simply replace `return super().form_valid(form)` with `redirect(reverse('YOUR_TARGET_VIEW'))`. If you have other mixins within your view that rely on `form_valid` you may also call `super().form_valid(form)` prior to returning the redirect reponse but without returning its returned data further.

As of displaying error messages you may refer to [the django message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/).

EDIT: A cleaner way to do this, may be to overwrite `success_url` within your processing but this may not be appropriate to all use cases as you need to provide usefull defaults within each request path.